# capistrano-sidekiq not "Starting processing"

Tags: sidekiq, capistrano3

I am not sure what I'm missing but somehow I don't get the line:

```
INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

which does show up if I start sidekiq manually from the prompt line.

I am having this error because I am using capistrano-sidekiq to manage sidekiq withing capistrano, in the log file all I got is:

`Booting Sidekiq 4.1.1 with redis options 
INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.1 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379/1", :namespace=>"MyApp_staging"}
INFO: Running in ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org`

Because the last line is missing

> ...Starting processing...

no jobs are processed.

When I run:
`bundle exec sidekiq -e staging`
every job is processed just like it should.

Any idea what could be the reason? I've [shared](https://gist.github.com/embasbm/0b4213262685c9eaed7aeff0097bf895) the important files code, if it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano daemonizes.  Sidekiq does not print out that line if you daemonize.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb#L80